# device memory absolute path (android)

Tags: android, memory, filepath

I haven't got a SD card on my device, but there's a lot of free space in its own memory

I have something like this:

```
private static final String MEDIA_PATH = new String("/Samsung/Music/");
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
if (home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new Mp3Filter())) {
                songs.add(file.getName());
        }
}
```

`Mp3Filter` works properly, but it doesn't work. I think that there's something wrong with `MEDIA_PATH`, what should I write there?

Comment: "Mp3Filter works properly, but it doesn't work."? What does the log say?

Comment: could you specify where i should look for the log? i'm very sorry, but i'm new to android-programing. device suggests me to force close the application

Comment: I'm talking about logcat: http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html

Comment: 11-28 23:55:56.705: E/AndroidRuntime(24389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shchurov/com.shchurov.AudioplayerActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException  // is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `String.format("/data/data/%s/", context.getPackageName());`

Comment: if i understand you right: `MEDIA_PATH=String.format("/data/data/%s/", context.getPackageName());` this way it says that context cannot be resolved

Comment: Activity and many other android classes extend Context. Context is your best friend. Befriend context. :)

Comment: ok, i see what you did there) but even this doiesn't work `MEDIA_PATH="/data/data/";`

Comment: Well, this should answer your path issue question. I would look somewhere else in your code, or begin developing this test first.